# Construct a new array out of an existing array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an `$accounts` array with this data in it

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:25 [▼
    "email_address" => "bob@xyzcorp.com"
    "account_id" => 111
    "password" => "abc"
    "account_type" => "admin"
    "name_prefix" => "Mr"
    "first_name" => "Bob"
    "middle_names" => "X."
    "last_name" => "Jones"
    "name_suffix" => "Jr."
    "non_person_name" => false
    "DBA" => ""
    "display_name" => "BobJ"
    "address1" => "111 Park Ave"
    "address2" => "Floor 4"
    "address3" => "Suite 4011"
    "city" => "New York"
    "state" => "NY"
    "postal_code" => "10022"
    "nation_code" => "USA"
    "phone1" => "212-555-1212"
    "phone2" => ""
    "phone3" => ""
    "time_zone_offset_from_utc" => -5
    "customer_type" => 2
    "last_updated_utc_in_secs" => 200200300
  ]
  1 => array:25 [▼
    "email_address" => "tom@xyzcorp.com"
    "account_id" => 112
    "password" => "abd"
    "account_type" => "mbn"
    "name_prefix" => "Mr"
    "first_name" => "Tom"
    "middle_names" => "Z."
    "last_name" => "Smith"
    "name_suffix" => "Sr."
    "non_person_name" => false
    "DBA" => ""
    "display_name" => "TomS"
    "address1" => "112 Park Ave"
    "address2" => "Floor 3"
    "address3" => "Suite 3011"
    "city" => "New York"
    "state" => "NY"
    "postal_code" => "10022"
    "nation_code" => "USA"
    "phone1" => "212-555-2323"
    "phone2" => ""
    "phone3" => ""
    "time_zone_offset_from_utc" => -5
    "customer_type" => 2
    "last_updated_utc_in_secs" => 200200300
  ]
]
```

---

I want to construct a new array out of this array. 
But the new array I only want to have 2 keys:  `email_address` and the `password`.

**I've tried:**

```
$new_array = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($accounts as $account) {

  $new_array[$i++];

  foreach ($account as $user) {
    $new_array['email_address'] = $user['email_address'];
    $new_array['password'] = $user['password'];
  }
}

dd($new_array);
```

I hope someone can give me a little push here.

Comment: You are missing a semicolon in this line `$new_array[$i++]`

Comment: The error message `syntax error, unexpected ...` usually means you forgot to end the previous statement with a semicolon (`;`).

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot that.

Comment: what is `dd($new_array);` ?

Comment: `dd` is like a php die/dump. I used to see what got stored in my `$new_array` variable.

Comment: That `dd` line never get executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not adding new elements to `$new_array`. Each time through the `foreach` loop you overwrite the same two keys. The elements of `$new_array` should be arrays.

You also don't need the inner loop, because each account is just one user.

```
foreach ($accounts as $account) {
    $new_array[] = array('email_address' => $account['email_address'],
                         'password' => $account['password']);
}
```

You don't need the variable `$i`, because `$new_array[] =` pushes a new element onto the array.

Comment: Wow, that's kind of neat ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  $new_array[$i++];
>
>   foreach ($account as $user) {
>     $new_array['email_address'] = $user['email_address'];
>     $new_array['password'] = $user['password'];
>   }
> ```

Your issue is here, you almost have it, but as you are using the array *within* the array, with the two sets of `foreach` loops, you thus need to have the same depth of structure if you want to preserve more than one records' `password` and `email_address`.

So, replace the above quote with:

```
$i++
 $new_array[$i];

  foreach ($account as $user) {
    $new_array[$i]['email_address'] = $user['email_address'];
    $new_array[$i]['password'] = $user['password'];
  }
```

This will output

```
$new_array(
    [0] ===> ['password'] --> {data}
        ===> ['email_address'] --> {data}

    [1] ===> ['password'] --> {data}
        ===> ['email_address'] --> {data}
    ....
)
```

**Edit:**
This can further be reduced and tidied up as:

```
   $i++
     $new_array[$i];

        $new_array[$i]['email_address'] = $account['email_address'];
        $new_array[$i]['password'] = $account['password'];
```

Because you know the key of the value you want so you don't need to break the outer array apart to find anything, you can get it by direct reference to *outerValue* (`account`) and then *key*(`email_address`, etc).

Comment: I really appreciate your help.